# C# detect quotes in a text file

Tags: c#, readfile

I try to detect quotes in a loaded text file but it is not working. I have tried with '"' and '\"' without success. Any suggestion? thanks

```
 void read()
 {
    txt = File.ReadAllText("txt/txttst");

    for(int i=0;i<txt.Length;i++)
    {
        if(txt[i]=='"')
        {
            Debug.Log("Quotes at "+i);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is exception or ?

Comment: `"txt/txttst"` is an *odd* file name... something like `@"c:\mydata.txt"` is expected

Comment: There is no exception, it just doesn't output anything. If I type  txt = "\"hello";
instead of txt = File.ReadAllText("txt/txttst"); then it works. 

In Unity3d any non-full path relate to the Asset folder. I can read the file no problem, but I cant detect the quotes.

Comment: Put *break point* on `for`, inspect `txt` value. Is it valid text? Put *break point* on `Debug.Log`. Have you stopped on this break point?

Comment: Are you sure that you file really contains `"`? Also, what encoding is used in that file? If it's something like ISO 8859-7, reading it with default encoding (UTF-16) is not a good idea. @zar-shaikh has shown you how to read file using UTF-8 encoding, you could use his snipped to load file with proper encoding. Also, @dmitry-bychenko has a nice advice - try to inspect the value of `txt` (either by debugging or printing it out to console).

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
  string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"txt/txttst");

        for (int i=0;i<lines.Length;i++)
        {
            string line = lines[i];

            // ASCII Code of Quotes is 34

           var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line.ToCharArray()).ToList();

            if(bytes.Count(b=> b.ToString()=="34")>0)
                Console.WriteLine("\"" + "at line " + (i + 1));

        }
```

Comment: I am on mac, maybe it is a mac problem? can anyone try this code line with Unity and let me know if it works on your system? cheers

Comment: - When i read the text in the file out on the console the quotes appear. 
- One of my friend tried the code on his mac and it worked fine. 
- Maybe it has to do with the file's encryption then I will try to figure this out.

Comment: `// ASCII Code of Quotes is 34`: I think you mean that, in UTF-8, the code units for a [quotation mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm) character are { 34 }—and it's nice that it's only one and that 34 is not included in the code units for any other character—so you can search just for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it, please see the code and screenshot below. Hope it helps.

```
namespace TestConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string txt = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\test.txt");

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\test.txt");
            var reg = new Regex("\"");

            Console.WriteLine("Contents of test.txt are; ");

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);


                var matches = reg.Matches(line);
                foreach (var item in matches)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Quotes at "+ ((System.Text.RegularExpressions.Capture)item).Index);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem, my text editor did a subtle auto-correct from " to “ . Cheers.